# NetworkStream.Write data seems not to arrive at receiving socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

C# System.Net,Sockets

I'm having a problem where I cannot figure out what I might be doing wrong.

The story is, I send byte[] application data from TcpClient socket to another TcpClient socket. It all works great, until I add a custom pseudo Athentication test before the application data is sent, after which the send and receive which originally worked, fails.

I say fails, but what actually occurs is that it only appears to get 3 bytes all set to 0 at the read socket.

The Authenticate method does the following. 
The server end sends 1 byte of data (0-85), the client receives it, treats it as an int, multiplies it by 3 and sends a byte back to server. Server checks the value, and sends another byte back set to 1.

All of that seems to work fine, but together the data sent by cliend after authentication does not appear to be received, just 3 bytes set to 0.

I want the socket to remain open over the lifetime of the program, so I cannot dispose the stream, as that will also dispose the socket.

Here is the full code for both client and server, in the hope someone might see my mistake, or an issue I have missed.

The code is intentionally without error checking for brevity, and is very basic to just show the problem.

Note, that if both Authenticate methods simply return true, then the code works exactly how I'd expect it.

Server.

```
class Program
    {
        static Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Teddy\Documents\visual studio 2015\code\Readissue\TheClient\bin\Debug\TheClient.exe");

            Console.Title = "Server";

            TcpListener lis = new TcpListener(
                new IPEndPoint(
                    IPAddress.Any, 4000
                    ));

            lis.Start();

            TcpClient cli = lis.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream ns = cli.GetStream();

            if (Authenticate(cli, ns))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good!");
                // This condition is met
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }

            // Wait until Carrier class of client
            // Sends data
            while (!ns.DataAvailable)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("DataAvailable");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            //bytesread is always the value of 3.
            int bytesread = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Substring(0, bytesread);
            Console.WriteLine(sdata);
            Console.ReadLine();

            p.Kill();
            p.Close();

        }

        private static bool Authenticate(TcpClient cli, NetworkStream ns)
        {
            //return true;
            byte[] rcv = new byte[1];
            int isnd = rnd.Next(0, 85);
            byte[] snd = new byte[1] { (byte)isnd };

            //Sends a random number
            //and waits for response
            ns.Write(snd, 0, snd.Length);
            while (!ns.DataAvailable)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            // Expects response to be 
            // random number x 3
            int br = ns.Read(rcv, 0, rcv.Length);
            int ircv = rcv[0];

            int iok;
            if (ircv == (isnd * 3))
            {
                // Confirm random number x 3
                iok = 1;
                byte[] bok = new byte[1] { (byte)iok };
                ns.Write(bok, 0, snd.Length);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                iok = 0;
                byte[] bok = new byte[1] { (byte)iok };
                ns.Write(bok, 0, snd.Length);
                return false;
            }
        }

        class Carrier
        {
            public double PointX { get; set; }
            public double PointY { get; set; }
            public string Comment { get; set; }

            public Carrier(byte[] bytes)
            {
                string[] tmpStrings = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
                    .Split('|');

                PointX = Convert.ToDouble(tmpStrings[0]);
                PointY = Convert.ToDouble(tmpStrings[1]);
                Comment = tmpStrings[2];
            }
        }
    }
```

Client

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";

            IPEndPoint EP = new IPEndPoint(
                    IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), 4000
                    );

            TcpClient cli = new TcpClient();
            cli.Connect(EP);
            if (!cli.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not connected!");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            NetworkStream ns = cli.GetStream();

            if (Authenticate(cli, ns))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good!");
                // This condition is met
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad!");
                return;
            }

            // Send data to server
            Carrier carrier = new Carrier();
            string stringtosend = carrier.ToString();
            byte[] bytestosend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringtosend);
            ns.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Data sent!");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static void UseClient(TcpClient cli, NetworkStream ns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ns.CanRead);
        }

        private static bool Authenticate(TcpClient client, NetworkStream ns)
        {
            //return true;
            byte[] rcv = new byte[1];
            while (!ns.DataAvailable)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            int br = ns.Read(rcv, 0, rcv.Length);
            int ircv = rcv[0];
            int result = ircv * 3;
            byte[] snd = BitConverter.GetBytes(result);
            ns.Write(snd, 0, snd.Length);

            while (!ns.DataAvailable)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            br = ns.Read(rcv, 0, rcv.Length);

            int iok = rcv[0];
            if (iok == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    class Carrier
    {
        public double PointX { get; set; }
        public double PointY { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }


        public Carrier()
        {
            PointX = 1.00;
            PointY = 2.00;
            Comment = "A longer comment string";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return PointX.ToString() + "|"
                + PointY.ToString() + "|"
                + Comment;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You code just terminates after sending one message.  You need a loop to stop the code from terminating which is normally referred to as a BLOCK.  You can use a WAITONE to block.  See the msdn asynchronous examples on following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx  Note : the msdn example also terminates after a couple of messages.

Comment: I was under the impression Console.ReadLine(); kept the code alive.

Comment: Yes Readline will block, but you are using Synchronous methods and you have no loop to process more than one message.

Comment: I know, synchronous is what I want, can you explain how having a loop will help toward solving my problem, I don't think I need a loop to send more messages if I cannot even successfully send one.

Comment: There are 7 network layers.  Your code has the transport layer with the client and server.  You are missing the application layer.  The application layer the client sends a message, the server receives a message and processes the message, and then the server sends a response.  The client receives the response and then sends the next message.  Does your code have the client sending multiple messages?  Can your server receive more than one message and respond to each message?

Comment: yes my setup works just fine, except when I use the Authenticate method.

Comment: A client sends a message and then waits for a response from server.  This normally is referred to as a Master (Client)-Slave(Server) relationship.  The client for authentication doesn't look like it sends a message.  Just waits.

Comment: I'm happy to move this to chat, like suggested, but it says I cannot.

Comment: A server should never send a message until it receives a message from client.  It looks like the authentication methods in both client and server both send random number at same time.  The server should wait for a random number from client then send back a random number to client.

Comment: A server and client in this context are both just a clasd of TcpClient it does not matter which sends first . Both client and server Authenticate methods return true, I believe all the bytes sent though are stuck in the stream zdespite them all being successfully read.

Comment: TEDSON : Wrong! Wrong! Wrong!  Yes either end can send messages at the TcpClient is doesn't mean that you won't have a race condition.  That is why you need an Application level which which defines the messaging protocol.  There are lots of protocol like Master-Slave, Token Ring, But you need to make sure the server and client are synchronized.

Comment: My program is the application layer, and in my Authenticate method client waits until data is available, before reading and so does server, it is absolutely "synchronized",  client or server are not trying to send data at the same time, nor is one trying to send while the other is reading and visaversa, if that is what you mean by "race condition".

Comment: How can both ends of the connection can wait without one end sending?  You are sending random number at both client and server at the same time.  I think that is causing a synchronization issue later in the code.  Draw a state diagram?  It is not the fact you are sending at same time, it is your waiting and sending that is the issue.  The server should never send anything until the client request the info so you operate as a master-slave.  When the server send without a request then the client doesn't know if the receive is a response from a request or a request from server.

Comment: I don't know what else to say, I believe you must not have even looked at the code, which is full and complete. Perhaps you can quote the line in client code where it sends a random number or even where a Random class is used or declared. Also I am grateful for your time and interest.

Comment: Sorry about mistake.  Check the actual number of bytes receive and see if you get the correct number.  If the keep alive option is set you can get zero byte tcp messages with no data.

Comment: when sending the actual data as binary array (3 doubles and a string) 47 bytes are sent by client, after the read by server, the bytesread variable is equal to 3. A breakpoint reveals all those bytes to be 0 (zero). Exactly yhe amount of bytes sent in total between server and client during the Authentication process (which completes successfully and returns true in both methods.

Comment: The Authenticate in client is sending an int which is four bytes (not  47).  The server is only receiving the first 3 bytes. With TCP there is no guarantee that all the data is received at one time. Data can be broken into various size datagrams with max ~1500 bytes.  You need to use following 1) Ascii:Terminate message with known char 2) Ascii or Binary : add a byte count to start of message then receiver waits until all bytes are rx 3) Ascii or Binary: Send fixed length messages. You are using method 3 but sending an int which is 4 bytes,but then in server looking for 1 byte the size of rcv.

Comment: Ok, Authenticate method in client is sending an int instead of a byte which server is expecting, server Authenticate method only passes a 1 byte buffer to the Read with a length of 1, so 3 bytes are left in the stream. If you would like to omit all the 1500 max bytes and the rest of the irrelevant stuff, I'm happy to accept that as an answer if you provide it. And please do because you've stuck with me here and I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not providing an answer because I don't like the code.  A server should never initiate a message.  I'm qualified to teach a college course on communications and don't like your code.

Comment: That...was a weird comment thread. I appreciate it's not the specific fix for this problem, but might I suggest including a Stream.Flush() call after each finished datagram Write - the actual sending of data is not guaranteed until you flush the network stream, and it'll avoid hard-to-trace buffering issues you might encounter.

Answer (score 2):

So as I suspected, the problem was in the Authenticate method on the client side.
I was sending an int instead of a single byte. The offending line of code was.

```
byte[] snd = BitConverter.GetBytes(result);
```

Which should have been.

```
byte[] snd = new byte[1] { (byte)result };
```

Thanks jdweng for finding the error.

PS, thanks to the down-voters for your interest, please accept my sincere pity.